# Comparing a matrix elementwise with an array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have a matrix with i rows and N columns and I have an array of 7 numbers. I want to compare all the numbers in my matrix with the array by row, and the numbers equal too one of the numbers needs to be appended. I have tried making for loops like this (The array3 is a csv file  I have changed to a numpy array. ):

```
def roundGrade(grades):
    array3 = file2.as_matrix()
    array1 = np.array([12,10,7,4,2,0,-3])

    o = []

    for i in range(len(array3)):
        for j in array1:
            if np.all(array3[i]) == np.all(array1):
                gradesRounded = o.append(array3[i])
            else:
                gradesRounded = 0
    return gradesRounded
print(roundGrade(array2))
```

However it says that elemtwise comparison is not possible like this. Is there any way I can use for loops for this comparison?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `np.all(array3[i] == array1):`?

Comment: Though your current comparison just compares two booleans, so I don't understand why you are getting that error. Please show the full error + traceback; it appears there is something you're not showing us.

Comment: You're also not using `j` from the for-loop: I'm not sure what the idea there is, but it's probably incorrect.

Comment: That did not seem to fix the problem unfortunately. Now it just prints array1

Comment: I thought that i had to use j, so that i did not use the same variable as the previous for loop.

Comment: Why are you looping through `array1`, if you're not using its elements separately? No need to loop in that case.